# How can I get my alert and function to work?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am building a quiz app, where once you select your response it will bring up an alert and then take you on to the next question.  The code I've built appears to build ok, however, when I test it in the simulator the alert or function does not work!  Can anyone see what I've missed?
Thanks

This is the code in order:

```
struct QuizView: View {

@State private var quiz: Quiz?
@State private var round: Round?
@State private var question: Question?
@State private var answer: Answer?
@State private var roundIndex: Int = 0
@State private var questionIndex: Int = 0
@State private var correctAnswers: Int = 0

@State private var showingScore = false
@State private var scoreTitle = ""
@State private var score = 0
@State private var showingAlert = false

private let jsonFile: String




var answers: [Answer] {
    return question?.answers ?? []
}

init(_ json: String) {
    jsonFile = json
    
    
}

private func loadQuiz() {
    quiz = Bundle.main.decode(jsonFile)
    round = quiz?.rounds.first
    question = round?.questions.first
}




private func onAnswerTap(_ answer: Answer) {
      if answer.correct {
          scoreTitle = "Correct"
          score += 1
      } else {
          scoreTitle = "Wrong"
      }
  }
```

then the rest looks like this:

```
var body: some View {

    ZStack {

    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.white, .black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        .opacity(0.5)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        VStack(spacing: 40.0) {
            Text(question?.question ?? "")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)                    
        
            ForEach(answers, id: \.answer) { answer in
                Button(action: { self.onAnswerTap(answer) }) {
                    Text(answer.answer)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .font(.body)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .onTapGesture { self.onAnswerTap(answer) }
                }
            }
            
            

            
            
            .alert(isPresented: $showingScore) {
                                Alert(title: Text(scoreTitle), message: Text("Your score is \(score)"),
                                    dismissButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {
                    
                            })
            
            
            
            
            }

       
     
  
        }
    .onAppear() {
        loadQuiz()
    }
    
    

                }
    


    
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
}

}
```

Comment: I can help you with this, but I need the whole code file so I can build for myself and see what's going on.

Comment: Where is your code to change showingScore value?. If it alway false, alert never show

Comment: @Luffy  I have now put the complete code up!  Thanks for the help

Comment: @HồngPhúc I have now put the complete code up! Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for the code! I tried doing the same thing as you did for `.alert(isPresented:)`, and it worked for me. I created a project without a `JSON` file, so no idea what's wrong with your code. Try adding `print()` statement for each action you have in your project and see if they get printed. Also, try adding this: 
`.alert(isPresented: $isAlert) { () -> Alert in Alert(alert code)}`